Fastest way to generate numbers up to a range in Python
I want to create a list of numbers that contains three consecutive 1s in its binary representation. To do this, I make set of number up to 2**n, and subtract it with a set of numbers that contains NO three consecutive 1s to get the result. No need for iterator or anything, just a set of number so I can do set subtraction (basically I have another set of numbers, and I want to subtract the set of all numbers from 0 to 2**n-1 with it).
Right now I'm using {i for i in range(2**n)}, which is pretty slow when n is about ~30. I tried using np.arange, but it's even slower. What would be the fastest way of doing this?

How long do you expect it to take to generate a set of about a billion integers?

just create a range-like  class, and implement the set-methods you will use into it: you  really don't need all thenumbers to exist "physically" in memory, since its trivial to know which are the set members.
Not saying any operations you want to perform on this many numbers will be fast.

Consider iterating range(2**n) and testing if the number is in the subtrahend, rather than materializing the minuend.

I'm not convinced you should build that set and do the subtraction. Better ask about what you really want.

The set you want to produce by set subtraction is almost certainly not a good tool for whatever job you're hoping to use it for. You should look for a fundamentally different approach to solving your underlying problem.

You problem sounds similar to the problem of how to allocate and free objects from  a "memory heap." In essence, a memory heap is a set of addresses that are "free," and allocating a contiguous block of addresses "subtracts" them from the set. Computer scientists and software developers have spent more than half a century inventing and tweaking algorithms for heap management. Maybe one of those algorithms would solve your problem.

How much memory do you have?

@nocomment She must have a very large amount of RAM if she can create set(range(2**30))

I edited the question to add more information of what I want to do!

"I want to create a list of numbers that contains three consecutive 1s in its binary representation." - Why? What are you going to do with them?

Actually, I'll later use it as a list and iterate over them. Basically I have a task where if I detect a 1 in the string I do a certain task, and if I detect a 0 I do a different task. And I check this over all possible combinations that contain three consecutive 1s. Perhaps I should ask another question, since the bottleneck probably won't come from generating the numbers anyway.

@SIGHUP Just curious: How do you know they're female?

@nocomment I don't. 50/50 guess

@KimDong if n == 30 and hence your range is 2**30 then the number of values that match your criterion of having at least 3 consecutive 1-bits is 974,791,728. That's an awful lot of data and I can't help but wonder if Python is the ideal platform for working with values of that magnitude.

@SIGHUP How did you get the number? I was tired/lazy so wrote a program. Is there a "math way"?

@nocomment I wrote brute force code. I don't know if there's any other way

I tested your solution
{i for i in range(2**n)}

against just doing set(range(2**n)) for n equal 10 using timeit, results at my machine are as follows
python -m timeit "{i for i in range(2**10)}"
10000 loops, best of 5: 35.6 usec per loop
python -m timeit "set(range(2**10))"
10000 loops, best of 5: 21 usec per loop

so latter is faster, but order of magnitude is same.

What would be the fastest way of doing this?

If you are able to provide enough disk space, you might try create your giant set once and pickle it to file, then load them when you need it. You should then test if it is faster on your machine or not.

How about n=20?

"create your giant set once and pickle it to file" — that's unlikely to be faster.

@nocomment for 2**20 I got 5 loops, best of 5: 77.3 msec per loop and 5 loops, best of 5: 63.1 msec per loop respectively so again latter is faster and order of magnitude is same

Yes, and they're closer together and it's more like their 30. I don't see why you used the very small n=10.

I think the faster solution is to generate them.
The idea is to start with the simplest case:
only 3 consecutive 1
Given N=5 there are only 3 solutions:
11100
01110
00111

This can be implemented using a code like this:
from collections import deque
N=5
S = deque('111'+'0'*(N-3))
for _ in range(N-2):
    print(''.join(S))
    S.rotate()

This shifting technique, allows us to see the problem from another angle,
explore all valid '3 consecutive 1' (3c1) having the left and right remaining part all equal to 0 '0'*(N-3)
[left]<3c1>[right]

Now the problem is generating all the remaining numbers for left and right.
We need an algorithm able to Generate them for all lengths from 1 to N-3
It is not clear to me if 4 consecutive 1 are valid, or multiple 3c1 are valid as well, in any way this can be implemented in this piece of code.
Supposing all other cases are allowed, we can generate them using itertools:
itertools.product('01',repeat=n)

Putting all together:
shift the three ones from left to right
at each step we generate all other remaining part both for left and right
Example with N=5:
Step 1:
left: lengt=0
right: lenght=2

['111'+''.join(r) for r in itertools.product('01',repeat=2)]
Out[3]: ['11100', '11101', '11110', '11111']

Step 2:
left: lenght=1
right: lenght=1

[''.join(l)+'111'+''.join(r) for r in itertools.product('01',repeat=1) for l in itertools.product('01',repeat=1)]
Out[5]: ['01110', '11110', '01111', '11111']

Step 3:
useless to explain.It should be already clear
This code explains a possible algorithm to generate the numbers but has no optimization at all. I think some profiling should be used to address further opt. maybe numpy, or create the left/right set and load it can give good speed-up.

How would you adapt this for the range(2**30) ?

In the example N represent the number of bits used, so for 2^30 N should be 30.
This is oneliner solution: set([''.join(l)+'111'+''.join(r) for offset in range(N-3) for r in itertools.product('01',repeat=N-3-offset) for l in itertools.product('01',repeat=offset)])
it takes less 1sec for N=20, 1min for N=25

Then you don't produce all possibilities and for N=20 you generate 2,228,224 strings, way more than even 2^20.

Also, using a list comprehension seems just silly, why not use a set comprehension?

This was just an example, of the algorithm, int(x,2) should transform the string representation into the final number.  Right for set comprehension.

The point wasn't the string type but the number of them. You generate so many duplicate candidates that you even generate more than 2^N. For N=30, your corrected code would go through 3758096384 candidates, that's 3.5 times 2^30.

So it would probably be faster to just go through the 2^N ints with for i in range(2**N): and check them with if i & (i>>1) & (i>>2):. Demo.

@nocomment I like your algorithm so this is not a criticism - merely an observation. Tests on Apple M2 reveal that shifting is slower than floor division - not by much but it is slower. I think that's always been the case. There seem to have been improvements in 3.13.03b where both shifting and floor division appear to be faster than in 3.12.4 with floor division still outperforming shifting

@SIGHUP Ah right, the arithmetics tend to be faster on small numbers and these are small. I guess lately I've used larger ints more often and got into the shifting habit. Oh well, this is like an XYZ problem anyway, where the OP wants to do X, tries to do X with Y, tries to do Y with Z, and asks about Z while keeping X secret, and they should be doing neither Z nor Y at all.

@SIGHUP I think shifting starts winning at N=31 here. For i=2**30-1, division is 6 ns faster for me but for i=2**30 it's 26 ns slower. And with N=31, half of the i are 2**30 or larger.
